# Error creating Azure Table using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

Following the steps in this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet), I created a console application and added the following code to the main method:

```
            string connection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyStorageAccountName;AccountKey=MyAccountKey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

        CloudStorageAccount account;
        if (!CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connection, out account))
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to parse storage account connection string.");
        }

        CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("mytable");

        // this is the line at which I get the error:
        table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

However, I got the following error when executing the last line:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Note: I wrote similar code that targets the same storage account but to create a queue and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's time to delete packages folder for the solution and clean and rebuild project. Also make sure Microsoft.Data.OData nuget package is actually installed.:)

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Since you have installed WindowAzure.Storage(version 8.4.0) package, one of its dependencies named Microsoft.Data.OData(version 5.8.2) will also be installed. There might be some other packages which referenced Microsoft.Data.OData(version 5.6.2), it will cause the exception which you mentioned in your post.

To solve this issue, you could add the assemblyBinding in your configuration file(app.config). It will bind all the dependencies of Microsoft.Data.OData to the assembly you installed. The format of assemblyBinding is like following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" /></startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.8.3.0" newVersion="5.8.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.8.3.0" newVersion="5.8.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.8.3.0" newVersion="5.8.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```